# Find word in a string using a regex pattern lua

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I have a rest URL as a string --> `rest/dashboard/person/hari/categrory/savingaccount/type/withdraw`

In this I have to get the value between person and category && value between categrory and type. Because those value will dynamically change

**rest/dashboard/person/{{}}/categrory/{{}}/type/withdraw**

I tried with `string.gsub(mystring, "([%w]+%/)([%w%d]+)")`. But it seems it is not the correct wast to do it

Please help

Comment: `/(%w+)/category/(%w+)/`, and use `match` instead of `gsub`

Comment: ok sure i will try with match. Thanks Egor

Comment: local t = string.match("rest/dashboard/person/hari/categrory/savingaccount/type/withdraw" ,"/(%w+)/category/(%w+)/")

print(t) It is printing nil. Anything i am missing

Comment: You misspelled the word `category`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.match` with captures is the right tool for the job.
Try this:

```
s="rest/dashboard/person/hari/category/savingaccount/type/withdraw" 
print(s:match("/person/(.-)/category/(.-)/type/"))
```

Comment: thanks @ihf marking it as accepted answer. Any idea on what is wrong with thiss="rest/dashboard/person/hari/category/savingaccount/type/withdraw" 
local s1,s2,s3 = (s:match("/person/(.-)/category/(.-)/type/"))
print (s1)
print (s2)
print (s3)

Comment: @Hari, your `s:match` returns two values but the parentheses around it reduce them to one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lazy dot `.-` as suggested or a negated character class `[^/]+`

```
s="rest/dashboard/person/hari/category/savingaccount/type/withdraw" 
print(s:match("person/([^/]+)/category/"))
print(s:match("category/([^/]+)/type/"))
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/daLM4a)

Comment: Fantastic, this instance was extremely helpful for my use case.  Thanks!